# deploying play framework on Amazon EC2 using `sbt dist`

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, sbt, web-deployment, playframework-2.3

I am trying to deploy my play framework 2.6.x to the amazon EC2 instance.
I have made a zip successfully using `sbt dist` command. I have then copied the zip file to `/opt/{project-name}/` folder and unziped it there. I then tried running the application as a daemon with the following parameters and few more

`-Dhttp.port=80`

`-Dplay.http.secret.key={my-secret}`

`-Dconfig.file=/path/to/conf/prod.conf`

When I tried running the application using my EC2 public IPv4

`ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/login`

I got the host not allowed error for that IP. I then added the following to my `conf/application.conf` file:

`play.filters.enabled += play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter`

`play.filters.hosts {
  allowed = ["ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com", "localhost:9000", ".compute-1.amazonaws.com"]
}`

After doing all this, when I try to run the application I still get the following host not allowed error:

`BAD REQUEST`

`For request 'GET /login' [Host not allowed: ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com]`

Any help would be much much appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: I tried `allowed = ["."]` this option too. Still it says host not allowed.

Comment: Double check the right config is being picked up by printing the value of `allowed` like so: `println(config.get[Seq[String]]("play.filters.hosts.allowed"))`

Comment: thank you so much @MarioGalic